# How to find position in for loop in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

`for (var i in options)    Text(i);`

This is my for loop, I want to know the position of `i`  How to find that position.
I used that for loop in Flutter Widget.

I need the solution for use the for loop inside the widgets
I want to know the position of `i`

Comment: What you wanna do exactly ? you need to pass something from list ?

Comment: [ {
              fieldvalue: None
            },
            {
              fieldvalue: DailyThanthi(Tamilnadu)
            },
            {
              fieldvalue: HinduEnglish(Tamilnadu)
            },
            {
              fieldvalue: Website
            },
            {
              fieldvalue: Google
            },] . I want to pass the data Json to Widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```dart
for (int index = 0; i<options.length; i++) {
  var option = options[index];
  Text(option);
}
```

Edit:
Maybe a outer index variable will do.

```dart
int index = 0;
for (var i in options) {
  Text(i);
  index++;
}
```

Comment: we can't use that for loop inside the Widget I need the solution for this type for loop        `for (var i in options)    Text(i);`

Comment: @KumaresanJackie I edited my answer. How about this solution?

Answer (score 0):

`options.indexOf(i)` will return the index of the element

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your Suggestion. In my case options isn't the global variable